# How to create a child process with redirected only the input

Tags: winapi

To create a child process in pipe, there is a great example in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). When your parent process is a console application, you could handle the child process stdout by the following way easily:

```
HANDLE my_own_pipe_read_handle = 0, my_own_pipe_write_handle = 0;
// create pipe
CreatePipe( &my_own_pipe_read_handle, &my_own_pipe_write_handle, NULL, 0 );
// create STARTUPINFO
STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
ZeroMemory( &siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
// fill in STARTUPINFO
siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
siStartInfo.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
siStartInfo.hStdOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
siStartInfo.hStdInput = my_own_pipe_read_handle;
siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
```

My question is: what should I give to `hStdError` and `hStdOutput` value, when the host process is a Win32 (`WinMain`) application (so it has no standard output and standard error)? How would you do it?

Finally I solved my project on TCP/IP, many thanks for help. The current solution is future prof. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will have to provide a pipe for the output as well. This can lead to some tricky situations - I suggest you read Raymond Chen's [recent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/07/10183884.aspx) [posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/08/10184375.aspx) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't add the `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` flag in your `STARTUPINFO` structure. The handles will be ignored.

Comment: Unfortunately if I don't add this flag, I cannot create piped connection between the parent app and the child app standard input. [Check in MSDN!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331(v=VS.85).aspx)

Comment: I checked MSDN, but it your question that I missunderstood : I didn't get that you needed to read that child process stdout. @Jon answer is right.